# How to select row with the latest timestamp from duplicated rows in a database table?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with duplicate & triplicate rows - how do I select the rows that are duplicated but have the latest timestamp as well as the un-duped rows?

```
 -------------------------------------
| pk_id | user_id | some_timestamp    |
|-------------------------------------|
| 1     | 123     | 10-Jun-12 14.30   |
| 2     | 123     | 19-Jun-12 21.50   |
| 3     | 567     | 10-Jun-12 09.23   |
| 4     | 567     | 12-Jun-12 09.45   |
| 5     | 567     | 13-Jun-12 08.40   |
| 6     | 890     | 13-Jun-12 08.44   |
 -------------------------------------
```

So that I end up with:

```
 -------------------------------------
| pk_id | user_id | some_timestamp    |
|-------------------------------------|
| 2     | 123     | 19-Jun-12 21.50   |
| 5     | 567     | 13-Jun-12 08.40   |
| 6     | 890     | 13-Jun-12 08.44   |
 -------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT pk_id, 
       user_id, 
       some_timestamp, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY some_timestamp DESC) col 
FROM table) x  
WHERE x.col = 1
```

Comment: +1, I was waiting for someone to use analytic functions. dont you mean order by DESC?

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk: I have updated my answer with DESC clause. Please try now.

Comment: I am getting an ORA-00904: "X"."COL": invalid identifier

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
select * from table 
where some_timestamp 
   in (select max(some_timestamp)
       from table group by user_id)
```

Comment: That gives me an error - ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys plz try now

Comment: It's still going to fail - the second select returns more than one row

Comment: this time i tried it works for me. I put = there. it should be 'in'

Comment: sorry for my mistake @BedwyrHumphreys

Answer (score 2):

```
select YourTable.*
from
  YourTable JOIN
  (select User_Id, Max(Some_Timestamp) as Mx
   from YourTable
   group by User_Id) Mx
  on YourTable.User_Id=Mx.User_Id
   and YourTable.Some_Timestamp=Mx.Mx
```

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk my initial answer was not correct, this should give the correct results

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I made a SQLFIDDLE which returns the correct set of data

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable AS T1
INNER JOIN
( SELECT user_id , MAX(some_timestamp) AS some_timestamp FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY user_id
) AS T2
ON T1.User_Id = T2.User_Id AND T1.some_timestamp = T2.some_timestamp
ORDER BY 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7bba/6

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from my_table
where (user_id, some_timestamp) IN (select user_id, max(some_timestamp) from my_table group by user_id);
```

Comment: I tried Thomas Haratyk's solution and this one performs better.